# Generate data array from a vector of counts

Tags: r

Say I have a vector which is counts of the names, is it possible to create a data matrix from it?

I have a vector which is counts of the names as (the letters in the first row are names; and the numbers in the second row are the counts of it) :

> p0[,1]
>
> A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K
>
> 1  48 334 352 138  49   7  26  25  19   1

I expect to have a matrix like:
A B B B ... B(48 "B" in total) C C C C C ... C(334 "C" in total)...

Answer (score 2):

We can `rep`licate  the `names` of the vector with the values of that vector

```
rep(names(p0[,1]), p0[,1])
```